# How to select data using privacy settings?

Tags: mysql

There are events. Events can be private - only invited users can see its, public - visible for all, in group - only groups members can see its. Groups can be public or private. We shouldn't show events from private group.

```
event
id, title, group (nullable), is_private

event_invitee
event_id, user_id

group
id, title, is_open

group_participant
group_id, user_id
```

So now for displaying events available to current authenticated user we executing query something like (pseudocode):

```
SELECT
  e
FROM event e
  LEFT JOIN e.invitees i WITH i.user = :current_user # is current user invited to event ?
  LEFT JOIN e.group g
  LEFT JOIN g.participants p WITH g.user = :current_user # is current user are participant of group?
WHERE ((e.group IS NULL OR g.is_open = true OR (g.is_open = false AND p IS NOT NULL))
  AND (r.is_private = false OR (r.is_private = true AND i IS NOT NULL)))
  AND /* other filters, like by location */
```

**This is works well but very slooow. And there aren't possibility stale it. How it possible change structure for getting results faster and scallable?**

Comment: Rather than pseudocode, you should work out the actual query and [explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) to understand the index usage and possible optimization.  What have you tried to optimize the MySQL server and the queries so far?

Comment: @njk this is pseudocode.

Comment: @Stennie IMHO this task should be done not by MySQL but by Sphinx or MongoDB without this JOINs

Comment: JOINs aren't necessarily bad .. you haven't provided enough information to understand why the query is actually slow. What storage engine are you using in MySQL? How many rows are you joining? What does the explain look like? You may be missing some obvious tuning in MySQL, and moving to another product isn't a magic bullet. You can also remove some joins in MySQL by denormalizing the data. With a large selection of search criteria that need to be indexed, you are *possibly* better using a search engine like Sphinx or Lucene, but there may be a simpler optimization like tuning or caching.

Answer (score -1):

To make things speed up: you will have to rewrite your "left joins" to "where clauses". This is easier said than done. But it gives you the advantage to apply the filters that drop the most records out first. Let's say there is only 10 events in one location and a location filter is chosen then the query does not have to filter the private, public or group events not in that location. I know saying this is easy but no real code can be presented unless I can have some data. I hope this pointed you in the right direction. I managed to speed up an over 30 seconds lasting query to a bit more than 1 second. In the end it turned out we forgot to script the indices for the production database. So you can also add some well placed indices to speed things up.

Comment: uh. `left join to where`? you mean revert the old/bad `select ... from table1,table2,table3,... where ...` syntax? -1 for incomprehensible (and bad) suggestion.